# Erase a rect of an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview

I want to know, how can I erase a custom rect (with, for example, an `UIView` in `IB` or something else) of an `UIImageView` in order to display an other `UIImageView` positioned underneath.

[image]

I didn't manage to do it using some response in the forum...

Comment: have you tried masking image?
sample: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Comment: it's not really the same thing I tryin to do

Comment: Why not just bring the image into CoreGraphics and use `CGContextClearRect` or such?

Comment: Can you post some code to see how implement that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will clear a rect in an image:

```
- (UIImage *)clearRect:(CGRect)rect inImage:(UIImage *)image {

    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([image size], NO, 0.0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([image size]);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [image size].width, [image size].height)];
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

Just load your image and clear the rects before assigning it to the image view:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
UIImage *maskedImage = [self clearRect:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 50.0, 50.0) inImage:image];
[imageView setImage:maskedImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

probably not the best solution but you can do the other way and take the 4 parts around the rect separately and combine them afterwards without the inner rect. You would repeat this as long as you have rect's to crop out.

Comment: In fact, I find a QuarzCore or CoreGraphic way. But yes it could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot clear the UIImageView itself because this just draws the UIImage. So you have erase the rect in the UIImage. Create a bitmap context, draw the image into it. Erase the part you want to "see through" with CGContextClearRect. When create a new new image from the bitmap context.